# How could I prove this trigonometric identity?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Show that:

$$\left(\frac{1+\tan \theta}{1 - \tan \theta}\right)^n = \frac{1+i\tan n\theta}{1-i\tan n\theta}$$

Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Yxj.jpg

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$\left(\frac{1+i\tan\theta}{1-i\tan\theta}\right)^n$$ on the left hand side?

Comment: nnits like you see in my quest no more no lest

Comment: Dans ce cas là, you'll have a hard time proving it, because it does in general not hold.

Comment: so u haven t the aswer??

Comment: The answer is: as written it holds only for some special values of $\theta$ if any.

Comment: Where is this problem given ?

Comment: yes , but hwo can i preuve it

Answer (score 4):

The identity is false: for $\theta=\pi/3$ and $n=1$, the left hand side is
$$
\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{3})^2}{1-3}=-2-\sqrt{3}
$$
while the right hand side is
$$
\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{1-i\sqrt{3}}=\frac{(1+i\sqrt{3})^2}{1+3}=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
The correct identity is
$$
\left(\frac{1+i\tan \theta}{1 - i\tan \theta}\right)^n = \frac{1+i\tan n\theta}{1-i\tan n\theta}
$$
that follows at once by expanding
$$
\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}
$$
and recalling De Moivre's identity.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained by egreg, the identity
$$
\left(\frac{1+\tan \theta}{1 - \tan \theta}\right)^n = \frac{1+i\tan n\theta}{1-i\tan n\theta}
$$
is false.

However, the identity
$$
\left(\frac{1+i\tan \theta}{1 - i\tan \theta}\right)^n = \frac{1+i\tan n\theta}{1-i\tan n\theta}
$$
IS valid.

Indeed,
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1+i\tan \theta}{1 - i\tan \theta}\right)^n 
&=\left(\frac{\cos\theta+i\sin \theta}{\cos\theta - i\sin \theta}\right)^n 
=\frac{(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)^n}{(\cos\theta-i\sin \theta)^n}=\frac{\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta}{\cos n\theta-i\sin n\theta} \\= \frac{1+i\tan n\theta}{1-i\tan n\theta}.
\end{align}
We have used DeMoivre's formula:
$$
(\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta)^n=\cos n\theta \pm i\sin n\theta.
$$